# Looping through names when comparing dates

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

EDIT: I realized I had the wrong title. Sorry!

I am trying to write a formula that will compare the dates of sales to dates of follow-up contact within three days of the sale.

For example, given the data below:

```
            Sale           Follow-Up

Jim         06/15/2019     06/14/2019
Jim                        06/18/2019

Dwight                     06/06/2019
Dwight                     06/09/2019
Dwight      06/04/2019     06/11/2019
Dwight                     06/12/2019
Dwight                     06/15/2019

Michael     06/13/2019
Michael                    06/04/2019
Michael                    06/07/2019

Phyllis     06/18/2019     06/18/2019
```

I would expect to see:

```
            3 Day Contact?

Jim         1
Dwight      0
Michael     0
Phyllis     1
```

I have the equation to loop through follow-up dates and compare them to the sale date, but I am not sure how to make it loop through the names.

The equation to loop through follow-up dates is:

```
=IF(AND(MIN(IF([Follow-up] >= [Sale], [Follow-up])) =< 3, MIN(IF([Follow-up] >= [Sale], [Follow-up])) >= 0), 1, 0)
```

But now I need it to work for every name with variable numbers of follow-ups.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in one step,use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$16=F3)*(ABS($B$3:$B$16-$C$3:$C$16)<=3))
```

[image]

If you want to use a helper column:

Use this to get whether to count or not:

```
=--(ABS(B3-C3)<=3)
```

then you can use SUMIF to sum:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,F3,D:D)
```

[image]

Comment: So, first of all, thank you so much for taking the time to help me! Now, regarding your second solution, it appears to only be looking at empty FU cells. Let me try out your first solution! Ideally, it would be a combination of the two, a helper column to populate 1s and 0s that I can use SUMIFs for in myriad other sheets that rely on these numbers.

Comment: Alright, I think I thoroughly confused myself and others because of the "sale"/"follow-up" labels. While neither solution quite did the trick for me, I believe SUMPRODUCT is the start of the answer for me (and others who find this question later on).